# How to make Visual Studio debug session launch a cmd.exe replacement?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, console-application

Can I somehow setup visual studio to launch a cmd.exe replacement (on this case [TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html), from JP Software) console when debugging console applications?

I have it setup on the Tools Menu as an External tool with a start directory pointing to the project debug bin folder. But I'd like a more immediate access, just so hitting the F5 key (Start Debugging) would launch the application in this cmd.exe replacement instead.

Comment: In theory, VS uses the COMSPEC environment variable to respect user preference.  Try setting it to the path to TCC/LE.

Comment: hmm, wouldn't want to affect the whole windows environment for this. Or maybe I would. Let's give it a try first...

Comment: User-specific environment variables are available as well as system-wide environment variables.  That way if there are other users on that system, the default cmd.exe won't be affected.

Comment: Indeed. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I've set the system-wide COMSPEC, rebooted for good measure, but Visual Studio insisted on calling cmd.exe

Answer (score 2):

In the project properties for your console project select the debug tab. There are 3 radiobuttons there that specify how the project is started when you hit 'F5'. The default value is 'start project' in your case I assume you need to select 'start external program' and specify your cmd replacement with any arguments to get the debug app launched from it. 
For cmd.exe it would be the /c or /k option to launch something else from the command shell.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Clink](https://code.google.com/p/clink/).

It doesn't replace cmd.exe, but makes it something I can very much live with. By using Clink, I don't need to worry about injecting an alternative. Instead, cmd.exe works mostly as I'd like it to.